# What experiences count in the application for a MS Clinical Psychology Program?

Tags: research-process, masters, application, psychology

I'm a third-year undergraduate student (from South Asia) of BS Psychology and plan to do a master's in Clinical Psychology after I graduate. What are the type of experiences needed to strengthen my profile as a candidate, especially if I want a scholarship? I'm currently an RA for a professor and plan to do a clinical internship in the summer as well as a thesis next semester. However, I feel like my research experience is not enough for a master's application and I feel stuck on how I can improve this. There are no psychology labs offered here either to which I can apply. Could a job at my university's writing center (involves helping other students with their research/thesis) help? What other experiences (research or otherwise) count?

Comment: Is this question about the US or elsewhere?

Comment: For master's, I primarily plan to apply to the US, Canada, and Europe.

Comment: In Europe, research experience is not required to be admitted in master's degrees. After the Bologna process the enrollment in a master's degree became standard if you do a bachelor's. In many European countries  universities have special quotas for foreigner students and they charge higher fees, so it's relatively easy to be admitted on a master's program as they welcome the extra income.

Comment: In the US it is expected you're getting a degree like this to increase your salary, and you're expected to pay for the degree with your future earnings. There are not typically scholarships for these degrees. Even fewer that would be open to international students unless they're coming with funding from their home country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question will be largely country-specific. It sounds, however, as if you are thinking of applying for admission to a program in the United States or, given the proximity to Australia and New Zealand, to one of those countries.

In New Zealand and Australia, there are three different clinical degrees awarded:

1. Master of Psychology (Clinical), which in turn might be in clinical neuropsychology, or in a more generalist area. This degree would typically involve a relatively small research thesis together with a lot of clinical practica.
2. Doctor of Psychology: This is considered to be a "professional" doctorate rather than a research doctorate. There *will* be a research component, but definitely not equivalent to a PhD. There are many similarities to the MPsych program with considerable emphasis on clinical practica and done over 3-5 years. Completing a DPsych as opposed to an MPsyh will usually obtain you a concession on the required supervision period post-degree and prior to full clinical registration.
3. Doctor of Philosophy. Essentially a research degree in a clinical area with various options for undertaking concurrent coursework and practica. The way that the national registration authority views your degree will likely depend on highly individual specifics.

You ask about the relevance of prior experience ... Admission to all of three of the degree programs usually requires a 4-year bachelor degree, either a Bachelor of Psychology or a Bachelor of Science (or Arts) in psychology with honors (the fourth year). If your particular country does not offer a fourth year, you might be admitted to a preparatory "Masters preliminary" year, or more likely, to an honors program, before applying the following year for admission to a clinical program. Be warned, however, that scholarships for Masters degrees (not only in Australia and NZ but elsewhere) are hard to come by. In some places, they are absent entirely. You might have to pay for at least one year before considering applying for a scholarship.

Prior research experience, gained informally, is (from what I have seen) unlikely to get you further up the admission ladder. It might help your own development but don't count on it as being beneficial in your pursuit of particular degrees.

Finally, there is something that you didn't mention and perhaps haven't considered ... but should. Be sure that the country where you intend to do your clinical training is also a country whose degrees will be (easily, if not automatically) recognized in the country where you wish to practice. The process of having a foreign degree recognized can sometimes be almost as burdensome as obtaining the degree in the first place. Better by far to check that the degree you undertake will get you where you want to go.

### Response to comments

To consider, at this stage, the issue of being a research assistant (RA) or teaching assistant (TA) is, at this stage of your enquiries, probably far too early. In order to be able to secure a position as either a TA or an RA, you would need to enter Australia on a visa that entitled you to work. If you are planning to enter Australia as a student, then you would require a student visa. The likelihood of obtaining a visa that entitled you both the study and to work (more than a very small number of hours) is small. International education in Australia is big business; [very big business](https://universitiesaustralia.edu.au/media-item/international-education-adds-29-billion-to-the-economy/). Australia distinguishes strongly between a local student, who would be eligible for substantial government assistance with university fees, and a foreign student (who would be referred to as a "full-fee" student). I expect that you are likely to take a financial hit for at least one year unless you can secure a scholarship in your originating country to support you while you are overseas. [This page](https://www.education.gov.au/international-education/support-international-students), from the Commonwealth Department of Education, is probably as good a place as any to start.

AS for what experience will help you climb the admission ladder? The mandatory 4-th year of study, and good grades. There is no real shortcut; life is tough.

Comment: You've mentioned that prior informal research experience won't do much - so in that regard, what are the things that give you an edge on the admission ladder? And if not scholarships, if one can get an RA or TAship with a professor at the university, what estimated percentage of costs could they cover? Some people have said it can cover a decent amount of your tuition while others have said only a small percentage, so I was confused on that.